# How to deal with a race condition caused by using async/awaits within an RxJs observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an Ionic/Angular application where I am using `NgRx` for the state management. When I load my data I set various state flags, and then have a selector called isLoading where I just "and" each of the loading flags. This part of it seems to work fine.

However, my loading indicator show and hide is actually presented two async methods.

I have the following code, to show/hide this...

```
 this.subs.sink = this.store$.select(fromApp.isLoading)
    .pipe(switchMap(async isLoading => {
      this.logger.info(`is loading: ${isLoading}`);
      if (isLoading) {
        await this.presentDataLoading();
        this.logger.info(`is loading presented`);
        return of(isLoading);
      } else {
        await this.dismissLoaderIfPresent();
        this.logger.info(`is loading dismissed`);
        return of(isLoading);
      }          
    })).subscribe();
```

And these two methods look like...

```
protected async presentDataLoading(message? : string): Promise<void> {
        if (this.loaderBase != undefined || this.isLoading) {
            return;
        }

        this.isLoading = true;
        let loaderMessage = message == undefined ? this.translateBase.instant(ResourceKeys.vals.messageLoadingData) : message;
        this.loaderBase = await this.userMessageServiceBase.presentLoadingSpinner(loaderMessage);
        this.isLoading = false;
    }


    protected async dismissLoaderIfPresent() : Promise<void> {
        if (this.loaderBase == undefined) {
            return;
        }

        await this.loaderBase.dismiss().catch(error => this.loggerBase.error(`loaderBase.dismiss: ${error}`));
        this.loaderBase = undefined;
    }
```

So above I have used the `switchMap` to try and resolve my race condition, but is does not seem to be helping.

The logging out put is as follows.

```
    9:43:25 is loading: undefined
    9:43:25 is loading: true
    9:43:25 is loading dismissed
    9:43:25 is loading presented
    9:43:25 is loading: undefined
    9:43:25 is loading dismissed
    9:43:30 is loading: undefined
    9:43:30 is loading: true
    9:43:30 is loading dismissed
    9:43:30 is loading: undefined  <--- last emitted val is now false. Correct
    9:43:30 is loading dismissed
    9:43:31 is loading presented   <--- But I now have this just being called
```

So we can see the last value of `isLoading` to be emitted is undefined (which is correct).

But we see the log statement `loading presented` is the last to finish, so this is out of order, and I have a stuck spinner.

So I really need the contents of the "switchMap" to be "locked" until the promises have resolved, but I am not sure why `switchMap` is not doing this, as I am not returning an observable (i.e. via the `return of(isLoading);` until AFTER the awaits.

How can I handle this situation?

### Update

Taking notes of answers below, and now using `concatMap` (so the observables are not cancelled) and converting the promises to observables using `from`, I now have the following...

```
 this.subs.sink = this.store$.select(fromApp.isLoading)
    .pipe(concatMap(isLoading => {    
      this.logger.info(`is loading: ${isLoading}`);
      if (isLoading) {
        const obs =  from(this.presentDataLoading());
        this.logger.info(`is loading presented`);
        return obs;
      } else {
        const obs = from(this.dismissLoaderIfPresent());
        this.logger.info(`is loading dismissed`);
        return obs;
      }          
    })).subscribe();
```

So far this seems to be behaving as I want - log output

```
6:54:58 is loading: undefined
6:54:58 is loading dismissed
6:54:58 is loading: true
6:54:58 is loading presented
6:54:58 is loading: undefined
6:54:58 is loading dismissed
```

Comment: You can easily convert a promise into an Observable using the `from()` operator. I would recommend this as it is easier to understand a pure reactive data flows instead of interleaving Observables with async/await.

Comment: Ah yes! This is exactly what I have now tried (just before I saw this comment) - so updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A Simple Solution

Promises are eager, so they'll run even if nobody is interested in the results. Your promise is running before you even hand it to the switchMap to manage. Also, switchMap may not work as expected with promises since they cannot be cancelled. Perhaps use concatMap instead.

The way to fix this with the smallest change is to defer your promise,so it doesn't start until RxJS subscribes.

```ts
this.subs.sink = this.store$.select(
  fromApp.isLoading
).pipe(
  concatMap(defer(() => async isLoading => {
    /* Same code as before */        
  }))
).subscribe();
```

---

If you want to avoid all these edge cases, then stop interleaving `Promises` and `Observables`, just pick one. They do interoperate, but they're not designed with that in mind. Observables are lazy and can be cancelled while promises are eager and cannot be cancelled.

If you ever work in a software shop, they'll likely discourage or disallow this style of code. Switching between these two asynchronous libraries should be kept minimal and at the boundaries of your program modules/libraries.